# Error: Cron has not run recently. But it did!

Tags: 8, cron, log-messages

[image: Cron has not run recently, but it did]
I have a site (hosted on Acquia) which always return an error about cron not running on the Status report page, but it actually runs regularly and it does all the task attached to it.

Cron is running externally (through Acquia panel) and Automated Cron is disabled. The error appears regardless of the method I use to run cron (Drush, Admin UI, Externally).

I couldn't find any issue trying to debug this, it seems just a "false positive".

Any suggestion on how I could get rid of the error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it successfully completed?

Comment: Both watchdog and drush return `Cron ran successfully.` Regadless in the status I always get `Last run {few} seconds ago`. Also the associated tasks work fine (like sitemap generation, Solr index update, etc).